# Modal box confirming an action is done in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am searching for something like the UiActivityView (A View that will be shown in the center, a little transparent) which just can hold a string saying "Saving Done"

I could do this my myself, but I am pretty sure something like this already exists but I can't find it..

By the way, i am using swift

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are generally called HUD, there are many libraries that already offer this kind of functionality, one of the most known is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Sample code directly from their demo:

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkMark.png"];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
HUD.labelText = @"Saving Done";
[HUD show:YES];
[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2];
```

Here the final result for reference
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try [PKHUD](https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD). It's written in swift, but for iOS 8 only. You can use it as framework. And great tool for finding libraries in the future is [swifttoolbox.com](http://www.swifttoolbox.io).

Comment: Mhm. Actually I just need one small box. I feel like it's a bit too much to inject a complete framework for this...